# Why can't I do a new line in the GAE in my java app?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp

Why can't I do a new line in the GAE?

It doesn't work.

Code:
Timer.class:

```
public String list() throws InvalidProtocolBufferException{
        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        String adat = new String();
        for (RequestStatProto sList : lists){
            adat+="start_timestamp_milliseconds: \r\n"+sList.getStartTimestampMilliseconds()+newLine;
            adat+="http_method: "+sList.getHttpStatus()+newLine;
            adat+="duration_milliseconds"+sList.getDurationMilliseconds()+newLine;
            adat+=newLine;
        }
        return adat;
    }
```

test.jsp:

```
<% 
    Timer timer=new Timer();
    timer.setMem();
    pageContext.setAttribute("timer",timer.list());
%>

<p>
<b>Memcache Statisztikák:</b>
${fn:escapeXml(timer)}
</p>
```

How can I do this?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Don't use System.getProperty('line.separator') at a server. This will return the line seperator of the server and not the clients line-separator.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it renders to a web page, the line break `"\r\n"` or `"\n"` will not work, instead you will have to use a `<br \>`

Alternatively you should return the list to the JSP and iterate it there and add `<br \>` tags just as you have in your `RequestStatProto sList` loop currently.